# How to know parent menu of a given QAction?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a list of QActions, some are added to the top level menu and few are added to submenus of top level.

Is there any way to know parent menu name of each actions?

```
QAction *act;
```

I'm trying `act->parentWidget()`. But how can I get menu name from this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check if the result of `act->parentWidget()` if it is a valid pointer, if so you can manipulate as a normal widget.

To get the menu name, it depends on which widget you are using.

If is QMenu, you can retrieve the menu title via the title function.

```
QAction *act;
...
QWidget *widget = act->parentWidget();
if (widget) {
    QMenu *menu = dynamic_cast<QMenu*>(widget);
    menu->title();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Let me try this out.

I'm not very much experienced with casting too, so is dynamic_cast is safest way?

Comment: @Brijesh It's safe, but you should also take a look at [`qobject_cast`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#qobject_cast). More about that [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/metaobjects.html).