# Retrieve QMenu of a submenu

Tags: c++, qt, qmenu

I have a right click menu containing submenus. For instance, it looks something like this

```
man
animal -->
       cat 
       dog
```

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32006039/qaction-parent-menu?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) here suggests to use `action->associatedWidgets();` which returns list of widgets the current action is linked to.

**What do i want:**

I would like my menu to return `animal` everytime a `cat`or `dog` is clicked. Additionally, that the submenu is clicked.

Is it possible to do it without iterating through list of widgets?

Comment: The reason why is my menu could grow very large with menus and sub-menus. So i was wondering if it is possible to get just the name without iterating through the whole menu every time i perform a right click. Could you please post a brief iteration?

Comment: You can use `action->parentWidget()` and cast it to `QMenu`. Check out the solution from https://stackoverflow.com/a/25301108/7506407

Comment: @eyllanesc Well..not sure how i missed that post. It is clearly a duplicate i suppose. Thank you!